# How to save the file by giving the file name from grid row containing columns,name,date,device

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
    I have a Grid view With Name time , device , Upload control columns , When i click upload in Grid view , files will be uploaded and saved in a folder, but i need to save the file with name_time_device.. 

    How to do it any help??


    if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
    HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
    {
    HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
    //FileUploadData.tName = Request.QueryString["name"];
    //string fname = context.Server.MapPath("~/FileUploads/") + FileUploadData.Name + "_" + FileUploadData.Id + "/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + "/" + FileUploadData.deviceID + "_" + 
    string fname = context.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + file.FileName);
    file.SaveAs(fname);

    }
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed";
    context.Response.Write("File Uploaded Successfully!");
    } 

    File uploading and saving i am doing in javascript. the file is zipped..and saving it in uploads folder, but it need to be saved with name_id_date_device.zip..


I am using a function In that function i am using ajax call , above code is my generic handler to save the files..
```

file saving is from function, here while saving only i need to pass id_name_device so which ever user clicks upload and upload files his file will be saved by his id_name_device.zip..

```
Help??
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: oh sorry i forgot.. I am targeting ASP. any ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

Can you please speicify you are having problem in getting name, time, device from gridview or you have issue with file saving with name "name_id_date_device.zip"?
if you problem is saving file with a specific name and you are ok to get name, time or device from gridview then you should change this:

```
  string fname = context.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + file.FileName);
```

TO

```
string fname = context.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + "name_id_date_device.zip");
```

in this way your file will be saved with this given name.

if you want to add your flag with file name just concat it with your filename when you are saving.

```
string fname = context.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + "what_flag_name_time" + file.FileName);
```

.and if you have anyother problem please be more specific. Thanks

Comment: No I am getting the values from Query String That i need to pass in a function,Query String Has Name_id_device,

Comment: i think it does not matter you get value from query string or some where else..you need to put these in place of file.FileName. it should work because just i try it works for me.